# Mocking logging module to include debug, info, error, etc

Tags: python-3.x, unit-testing, logging, mocking, patch

I am having difficulty mocking the logging module to include all of the logging module functions without using several unique mocks. Here is an example that replicates what I want to achieve in test_init_with:

problem_logging.py:

```
# problem_logging.py

import logging

class Example:
    def __init__(self):
        logging.info("Example initialized.")
        logging.debug("Debug Info")
```

test_problem_logging.py:

```
# test_problem_logging.py

from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
from problem_logging import Example

class TestExample(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_logging = patch("problem_logging.logging", autospec=True)
        self.mock_logging.start()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.mock_logging.stop()

    def test_init(self): # Fails
        ex = Example()
        self.mock_logging.info.assert_called_once_with("Example initialized.")
        self.mock_logging.debug.assert_called_once_with("Debug Info")

    def test_init_with(self): # Passes
        with patch('problem_logging.logging.info') as mock_info:
            with patch('problem_logging.logging.debug') as mock_debug:
                ex = Example()
                mock_info.assert_called_once_with("Example initialized.")
                mock_debug.assert_called_once_with("Debug Info")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestExample()
```

Problem:

```
Error
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py", line 58, in testPartExecutor
    yield
  File "/usr/lib/python3.5/unittest/case.py", line 600, in run
    testMethod()
  File "/home/fred/unittest_logging/test_problem_logging.py", line 16, in test_init
    self.mock_logging.info.assert_called_once_with("Example initialized.")
AttributeError: '_patch' object has no attribute 'info'



Ran 2 tests in 0.016s

FAILED (errors=1)
```

I would like to be able to set up the mock in setUp() and use it throughout this entire TestCase to be sure I have access to all the different logging levels without a potential extra five layers of indentation, similar to how MagicMock can do with objects and their methods.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution to my problem. The **_patch.start()** method returns the MagicMock object needed to make assertions against.

```
# test_problem_logging.py

from unittest import TestCase
from unittest.mock import patch
from problem_logging import Example

class TestExample(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.mock_logging_module = patch("problem_logging.logging")
        self.mock_logging = self.mock_logging_module.start()


    def tearDown(self):
        self.mock_logging_module.stop()

    def test_init(self): # Fails
        ex = Example()
        self.mock_logging.info.assert_called_once_with("Example initialized.")
        self.mock_logging.debug.assert_called_once_with("Debug Info")

if __name__ == "__main__":
    TestExample()
```